# Sort array elements based on another array's keys

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, key

In my PHP file I have 2 arrays, in each one the keys are numbered from 0 to its last index, and they both contains the same array elements number, as they are containing data on the same contact, but each array contains a different data about the same contact, and each contact has an ID which is his index on the array.

I have sorted the first array descending according to the values, so the keys are in different sort, and the values are descending. I want to sort the second array, in the same way, so they would have the same keys order, and then to do `array_values` on both of the arrays, in order it to have new ascending keys order.

For example I have these 2 arrays:

```
$arr1 = array('0' => 'John', '1' => 'George', '2' => 'James', '3' => 'Harry');
$arr2 = array('0' => '12', '1' => '8', '2' => '34', '3' => '23');
```

I have sorted `$arr2` descending according to his values like this:

```
arsort($arr2);
// So now, $arr2 is "[2] => '34', [3] => '23', [0] => '12', [1] => '8'"
```

I want to sort `$arr1` in the same way so it will also be:

```
$arr1 = array('2' => '34', [3] => '23', [0] => '12', [1] => '8');
```

How can I do this so the arrays will be sorted in the same keys order?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Why is this related data in two separate arrays?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what your desired result is.  You say that you want `$arr1 = array('2' => '34', [3] => '23', [0] => '12', [1] => '8');`, but I don't think that's actually the case

Comment: @PatrickQ I think he meant `array(4) { [2]=> string(5) "James" [3]=> string(5) "Harry" [0]=> string(4) "John" [1]=> string(6) "George" }`, he didn't change the values.

Comment: @ishegg I think so too, but I'd rather not assume/guess

Comment: Agreed, though, if he meant what he wrote, wouldn't the solution be just `$arr1 = $arr2`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? Using `array_replace()`:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('0' => 'John', '1' => 'George', '2' => 'James', '3' => 'Harry');
$arr2 = array('0' => '12', '1' => '8', '2' => '34', '3' => '23');
arsort($arr2);
var_dump(array_replace($arr2, $arr1)); // array(4) { [2]=> string(5) "James" [3]=> string(5) "Harry" [0]=> string(4) "John" [1]=> string(6) "George" }
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FVIsd)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`array_multi_sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)? It rearranges all arrays to match the order of the first sorted array.

```
// as elements of $arr2 are shifted, corresponding elements of $arr1 will have the same shift
array_multisort($arr2, SORT_DESC, $arr1);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/3BWTC)

Answer (score -1):

So you have two arrays, so why not just loop over the second array and use its as a key order to create a new array using the the values from the 1st array..

```
$newArray = array();

foreach (array_keys($arr2) as $key) {
    $newArray[$key] = $arr1[$key];
}
// then apply sorting to new array
arsort($newArray);
```

Then simply print your new array `$newArray` to check your result.

`print_r($newArray)` or `var_dump($newArray)`

Expected output will be:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "John"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "James"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Harry"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "George"
}
```

Similarly if you want an opposite, Then change just replace $arr2 with $arr1 like wise.

```
$newArray = array();

foreach (array_keys($arr1) as $key) {
    $newArray[$key] = $arr2[$key];
}
// then apply sorting to new array
arsort($newArray);
var_dump($newArray)`
```

Expected output will be:

```
array(4) {
  [2]=>
  string(2) "34"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [0]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```